# Package Manager Console not found

Tags: visual-studio-2010, package-managers

`Package Manager Console` not found in `Tools` menu?? I am using `Visual Studio 2010`. I need to run a command in it `Install-Package Facebook` to avail Facebook SDK in C#.NET. Help!

Comment: You can install it from http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/27077b70-9dad-4c64-adcf-c7cf6bc9970c

Comment: You need to install microsoft visual studio 2010 service pack 1 to get this on your console.

Answer (score 51, accepted):

1. From the extension manager download : NuGet package manager
2. From the Visual studio 2010 go to <kbd>Tools</kbd> –> <kbd>Library Package Manager</kbd> –> <kbd>Package manager console</kbd>

Comment: @theB3RV It is the same but it's not called "Extension Manager...", it's called "Extensions and Updates..." in Tools.

Comment: In VS 2013 you go to Tools -> NuGet Package Manager -> Package Manager Console

Comment: In my case it is in.. Tools - > NuGet Package Manager -> package Manager Console

Comment: In VS10 I did Tools --> Extension Manager --> Tools --> Build --> Then search for "nuget package"... then install "NuGet Package Manager"

Answer (score 6):

you need to install [NuGet Package Manager](https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/27077b70-9dad-4c64-adcf-c7cf6bc9970c)

Comment: I didn't have the option for `NuGet Package Manager` until I installed this, now I do! Thanks

Answer (score 1):

From VS 2013

<kbd>Tools</kbd> –> <kbd>NuGet Package Manager</kbd>  –> <kbd>Package manager console</kbd>